# buy & hold equity calculation in tradingview strategy tester

Tags: tradingview-api

does anyone know how the buy & hold equity calculation in tradingview strategy tester is performed? I am wondering if it is taking into account fees or not? E.g. is the buy & hold equity calculation taking fees like management fees etc in ETFs into consideration or do you have to do this manually in the commission setting in the strategy tester?

or does anyone know the built in code for this?

all I find on TV is:

Overview: Buy & hold equity
This chart displays the return achieved if all funds (Initial Capital) were used to buy the security when the first trade is entered, and the position was held for the duration of the test period. You can hide/show chart elements by clicking on their corresponding button at the bottom of the tab.

but no detailed info